# How do I refresh all connected clients using Scaledrone?

Tags: javascript, html, scaledrone

I own a website where it is a chatroom that most of my school uses to talk. There are some annoying spammers and just recently I made a way to ban them but they have to refresh. Is there any way I can make a way  to refresh everyones screen who is on my website and have the spammer banned? It would also be useful to use this and refresh everyone when I release an update.

Is there a way to do this using [Scaledrone](https://www.scaledrone.com/docs/api-clients/javascript), which is the library that I am using?

Comment: Probably, but given that there's no code at all in the question, it'll be pretty impossible to say what you need to change to achieve it

Comment: What code would i put in there? like some source code because i have some password and stuff that i dont want to be out there

Comment: Well, you've figured out how to push new chat items to their screens, right? Same idea, except instead of displaying a new chat text, you do something else with the info.

Comment: @DumbCoder Not the whole thing. Details and *relevant* code of the approach you tried.

Comment: I used scaledrone

Comment: i deleted it because it made the website not run @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you are using Scaledrone, you can [listen for a specific message](https://www.scaledrone.com/docs/api-clients/javascript) and in the handler code call [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

From the Scaledrone link above. You need to modify this to work with whatever setup you have. Did you write the code for the chat site?

```
// Subscribe after the 'open' or 'authenticate' event from the Scaledrone instance
const room = drone.subscribe('room_name');

room.on('message', message => {
  // Received message from room
    const {data, id, timestamp, clientId, member} = message;
   if (member.id === myId && message ==='expelliarmus') {
      location.reload()
  }
});
```

Comment: how do i like call the location.reload() do i make a button that only i woud have or smth and then call it that way????

Comment: I just need it to refresh their screen i dont need a ban system or anything i just need it to refresh so that the code could update and it could notice that their banned

Comment: i wrote majority of html and made some js